# Excel VBA export to other excel workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I dont have plenty of experience in VBA excel so i could use some help.

I created an excel worksheet.

Now i want to create a macro which sends the data from my worksheet to other excel workbooks.

I want to use an if statement so if project name = "x" then the macro should send data to workbook "x" and rank the imported worksheets by date.

I found this on the web and had adjusted it a bit

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim Data As Range

    Dim myData As Workbook

    Worksheets("blad1").Select

    Set Data = Range("c2")

    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\locatie.xlsx")
    Worksheets("blad1").Select
    Worksheets("blad1").Range("a1").Select

    RowCount = Worksheets("blad1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("blad1").Range("A1")

.Offset(RowCount, 0) = Data

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Jeeped could you help me started pls?

Comment: try these links to get you started: [Contextures - Getting started with Excel VBA](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbagettingstarted.html) and [MSDN - Getting started with Excel VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx) and [Mr Excel - articles](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles.shtml) and [chandoo.org](http://chandoo.org/wp/excel-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example to copy a sheet into a new file:

```
IF projectname = "x" THEN 'you have to define projectname

OldName = ThisWorkbook.Name 'name of your open file
Workbook.Add 'Open new file
newName = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'name of the new file
Windows(OldName).Activate 'original file select
Sheets("Sheetname").Activate 'define Sheetname of your original file
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Workbooks(newName).Sheets(1)
Windows(newName).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filename1, FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False 'define filename1
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
```